# Cant open ports in VPS Win Server 2016(AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, port

i'm trying to open ports 7171, 7172, 80 in Windows Server 2016 at AWS.

I already opened them in Firewall, then i tried to turn firewall off but i still unable to acess my xampp website through port 80 using my ip and cant acess my game server(tibia) at port 7171/72.

I enter at portchecker.co and he still saying that all of then are closed.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your VPS in AWS, having the ports open on the OS level is not sufficient. 
You should have the rules set at security group(SG) level and at network access control list if any is being used.

Comment: Going to try it at home tonight. Thanks for your help. Is there any tutorial to set these rules?